# Div “flickers” on page/window scroll in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, scroll, safari

Trying to fix div "flicker" on page scroll in Safari browser ( ver 12.0.2 on macOS High Sierra), but don't understand why this is happening, also i've tried to fix this via CSS methods, like `transformZ(0)`, `webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`, `webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d`, `will-change: top`, but this doesn't help, any ideas? thanks!

```js
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll').style;
window.onscroll = function () {
  scroll.top = middleOfScreen();
};

var raf = document.getElementById('raf').style;
requestAnimationFrame(function setRaf () {
  raf.top = middleOfScreen();
  requestAnimationFrame(setRaf);
});
  
function middleOfScreen() {
  return window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight/2 + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 20000px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  width: 23%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1em 0;
}
div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#static {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
#scroll {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24%;
}
#raf {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
}
#css {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=static>position:static</div>
<div id=scroll>set to top:50% onScroll</div>
<div id=raf>set to top:50% on requestAnimationFrame</div>
<div id=css>posision:fixed </div>
```

also **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/20yco/pen/aPEpGL)**

Comment: why would you use JS to accomplish this? css position:fixed seems to work fine

Comment: @peter because i need to `fix` div on something like `site builder` project where i have huge artboard with `x`and `y`scroll directions, div with `position:fixed` is fixed to any scroll direction, but i need only vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to set top every time your scroll event fire? it seems that setting top value affecting to the flicker. If you want to listen on scroll and set top anyway so I suggest to use throttle so your event listeners will do only once.

Comment: sounds interesting, can you make something like demo please? to understand which direction to think

Comment: I recommend this sample from lodash, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#throttle. I think lodash has quite good implementation for throttle